# jquery stretched background image slideshow with html and controls

Tags: jquery, background, fullscreen, slideshow, stretch

Thanks for giving your attention. I urgently need a solution to create background image slideshow with following requirements:

1. based on this jquery plugin - http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/ (or similar) to proportionally stretch images on the screen
2. must have slideshow ability to switch images with "Prev / Next" buttons
3. possibility to adjust slide/fade time, direction, effect(?), image position (center/top,etc.)
4. must have fade-in-out or ease effects while changing the images
5. ability to add name and long description (with html support) to each image, to show that name/description in some DIV on the front of the image when it's loaded
6. ability to turn-on/off preloading all images (progress bar would be fantastic)
7. if it could call back to some function would be great.
8. support of modern browsers, Ipad, etc.

I guess it may require some modification of the mentioned above plugin, or new coding.. anyway deeply appreciating any feedback from you.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This might save someone a click. The next hit on ddg.gg is:

http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_jquery_background_image_slideshow.html